# How to get user id from access token and pass it in url (Rewrite path) to services below

Tags: spring-boot, url-rewriting, spring-cloud-gateway

I am developing gateway with Spring Cloud Gateway. In gateway I want to extract user data (userId) from user's access token and pass it to the uri of below services (e.g /api/customer-info/${customerId}). The reason why I stuck is that URL rewriting happens before running filter which extract userId from the access token.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `AbstractGatewayFilterFactory` class. Here is an example:

```java
@Component
public class AuthenticatedUserInfoGatewayFilterFactory extends
        AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<AuthenticatedUserInfoGatewayFilterFactory.Config> {

    public AuthenticatedUserInfoGatewayFilterFactory() {
        super(Config.class);
    }
    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> newPath()
                .flatMap(path -> {
                    ServerHttpRequest.Builder requestBuilder = exchange.getRequest().mutate();
                    requestBuilder.path(path);
                    return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(requestBuilder.build()).build());
                });
    }

    private Mono<String> newPath() {
        return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .map(ctx -> (JwtAuthenticatedPrincipal)ctx.getAuthentication().getPrincipal())
                .flatMap(principal -> {
                    String path = Config.REWRITE_PATH_PREFIX + principal.getName();
                    return Mono.just(path);
                });
    }

    public static class Config {
        private static final String REWRITE_PATH_PREFIX = "/api/v1/users/username/";
    }
}
```

Above example uses spring security and username but you can replace `newPath()` logic to match your needs

Then register predicate in configuration file:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: authenticated-user
          uri: microservice-uri-here
          predicates:
            - Path=/incoming-request-path-here
          filters:
            - AuthenticatedUserInfo
```

**Note**: Class naming should follow the `*GatewayFilterFactory` and when registering in configuration file `*GatewayFilterFactory` part should be removed